# How to type a binomial tree with hanging branches

Tags: tables

I want to type up a binomial tree, except that each entry is a function (say a polynomial). If the polynomial is  typed in the usual horizontal style then the table becomes too wide and ugly. If the polynomial is typed vertically, inside standard tabular cells, then the table becomes too tall and disjointed looking. So I want to reduce the inter line spacing between the rows that separate pieces of the polynomial to make each polynomial look more like a single entity. I was wondering if there is a clean/ready-made solution.

Here is the schematics of what I am trying to type.

```
          A

          B   C

       D  E   F   G

    H  I  J1  K   L   M
          J2   

  N O  P1 Q1  R1  S   T  U
       P2 Q2  R2

V W X1 Y1 Z1  A1  B1  C  D  E
    X2 Y2 Z2  A2  B2
          Z3
```

Where the column Z1 Z2 Z3  is a typical polynomial  Z1+Z2+Z3

Comment: Please provide an MWE and let us know, if the `A B C` are just place-holders or if this is already the final result, you want to type. Do you need lines between the values? Have you tried `tikz-tree` or `forest`? Maybe you draw a little sketch!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The letters are place holders.  I think without lines it would be better, if the spacing makes each polynomial stand out. I will edit the table and add a WME next.

Comment: I think a drawing would be best. Do you want B aligned under A or B C centred below A?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  Here B and C are separate  entities. The tip of table is A, next row there are two elements B and C. After the second row each row has two additional elements on the left and right. The cells in the middle of each row gradually get to be longer. So [J1 J2] is one entity, so is [P1 P2], or [Q1,Q2] and so on. Each letter represents a relatively simple math formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand*{\rel}[1]{\mathrel{\mathllap{#1}}}

\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2ex, column sep=1em] % adapt that to your needs
&&&&A&&&&&\\
&&&&B&C&&&&\\
&&&D&E&F&G&&&\\
&&H&I
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
J_1\\\rel{+}J_2
\end{array}
&K&L&M&&\\
&N&O
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
P_1\\\rel{+}P_2
\end{array}
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
Q_1\\\rel{+}Q_2
\end{array}
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
R_1\\\rel{+}R_2
\end{array}
&S&T&U&\\
V&W
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
X_1\\\rel{+}X_2
\end{array}
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
Y_1\\\rel{+}Y_2
\end{array}
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
Z_1\\\rel{+}Z_2\\\rel{+}Z_3
\end{array}
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
A_1\\\rel{+}A_2
\end{array}
&\begin{array}[t]{r}
B_1\\\rel{+}B_2
\end{array}
&C&D&E\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]